# Proof of the paraxial law for Gaussian beams in laser design

Tags: optics, laser, laser-cavity

How does one proof that the complex beam parameter $q_1$ of a Gaussian beam is altered according to
$$q_2=\frac{Aq_1+B}{Cq_1+D}$$
when passing through an arbitrary optical element with a known ABCD (ray transfer) matrix?

Comment: Have you looked into any textbooks which discuss ABCD formalism?   In addition, please remember when posting to provide references, and above all **define all terms** provided.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I did, ABCD formalism for rays itself is well known to me. It's about the generalization to Gaussian beams. The book I'm reading "Laser electronics" by J. T. Verdeyen says "no [general] proof is known to this author"  on page 76. The people who would be able to answer this question are also familiar with the common symbols $q$ and $ABCD$.

Comment: The close reason you gave also doesn't make any sense, as the question is very specific about what it asks for. A lecture of the university of cornell available online (ECE4300 Fall 2016) also mentions that they don't know a simple way to derive the law. So I think the question is not entirely trivial.

Comment: The point is that people might be interested in doing their own investigation, but without defining $q_j$ there's not much to use as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scalar paraxial optics,  this must be  an example of the metaplectic representation of the symplectic group on Gaussian wavefunctions. There is a chapter-long discssion of this in "Symplectic Techniques in Physics" by Victor Guillemin and Shlomo Sternberg.

Comment: How advanced is the text? Makes me wonder whether there is not actually a simple reasoning for this very simple looking formula.

Comment: The derivation is in the first half of the book, which is intended as an undergraduate introduction to Gaussian/Hamiltonian optics. Nothing more than Gaussian integrals (although inticate ones!) are involved as paraxial is essentially the Fresnel approximation. Metaplectic is just a fancy word for Fresnel.

Comment: I will look into this. Thank you.